# Does the law of reflection apply to collisions b/w cricket bat and ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, reflection

In what direction does a ball go after hitting a bat on its plane surface?

Comment: You might want to look at ["Cricket Bat-ball Impact Mechanics: A Review"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ashish-Pandey-34/publication/345977459_Cricket_Bat-ball_Impact_Mechanics_A_Review/links/61a8743e50e22929cd3c77ce/Cricket-Bat-ball-Impact-Mechanics-A-Review.pdf), but the question is probably too general to answer. How much is the ball spinning? Is it hitting the sweet spot? What kind of [shot](https://www.viirj.org/vol12issue2/2.pdf) is the batter playing? How is the bat moving and rotating before the hit and twisting after? …

Answer (score 0):

If the bat is stationery, then laws of reflection apply well and good.

However, if the bat is moving towards the ball, the ball will have an extra x-component of velocity, therefore laws of reflection don't hold in such a case(from ground's reference point).

PS: I was very idealistic while answering.

Comment: Would the force exerted on ball be normal to the surface of bat at all times during collision? (Assuming the bat doesn’t move or rotate  much while the ball is still in contact, also ignoring friction)

Comment: Yes, reaction force always acts perpendicular